# Unbound variable

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

this is a bug I have found nothing about after a relentless search

I'm trying to run a bootstrap file in an EC2 instance, part of an EMR cluster v6.4.0. As the bootstrap action takes longer than 5 minutes, we execute it as a subprocess of the form

```
#!/bin/bash

var="var"
cat << EOF > ~/bootstrap.sh
intra="intra"
echo $var
echo $intra
EOF
/bin/bash ~/bootstrap.sh
exit 0
```

But the var "intra" is never set, and the bootstrap action returns the error line n: intra: unbound variable

If you execute that script the "intra" var is not printed.
Why can't I assign variables in a subprocess? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using that type of heredoc (`<<WORD`), you must escape literal `$` characters using `\$`. Same goes for the backtick character (`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
var="var"
cat << EOF > ~/bootstrap.sh
intra="intra"
echo $var
echo \$intra
EOF
/bin/bash ~/bootstrap.sh
exit 0
```

Another way of generating an equivalent bootstrap script is to use the literal heredoc form `<<'WORD'`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
var="var"

# This line will be inserted as-is without variable and subshell expansion:
cat << 'EOF1' > ~/bootstrap.sh
intra="intra"
EOF1

# We will allow this ONE line to expand.
cat << EOF2 >> ~/bootstrap.sh
echo $var
EOF2

# Back to literal insertions, no escaping necessary.
cat << 'EOF3' >> ~/bootstrap.sh
echo $intra
EOF3
/bin/bash ~/bootstrap.sh
exit 0
```

Inspecting the contents of `~/bootstrap.sh` is a good place to start debugging.

Comment: Perhaps emphasize that the *current* shell expands `$var` and `$intra`; the latter is apparently undefined. You can get an error from that with `set -u`; probably start using that.